# I need help make sense of TestDisk output

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I recently found an 2 TB external drive again which I though I ha lost and when I viewed it with DISKMGMT.MSC it said it had an unallocated section of 638GB.

[image: DiskMgmt results, six partitions in all, 2 internal and 4 on the external drive plus an un-allocated part]

I remembered that I might've deleted a partition by accident, and I tried to undelete it. During my research I used Testdisk to know more about the lost partition:

[image: first results:]

and I did what Testdisk calls a **DeepDive** on it. This resulted in the 14 screenshots of TestDisk you can see below.
My questions are:

- It seems that partition has been found but is unrecoverable, do you see that from the results?
- Which of the 14 highlighted lines points to the unallocated partition?
- How do I interpret these result? Can anyone specifically explain the columns, since they are very jumbled. What are the start columns, which are the end columns??
- If I re-allocated the **638GB unallocated part**, would I then be able to undelete missing files on that partition? Or will allocating it, wipe the disk totally clean.

Please share if you have **other** good ideas to salvage this.....

**EDIT 1:**

When I use the Powershell command Get-Partition, this is the result:

**DiskPath: \?\usbstor#disk&ven_usb3.0&prod__super_speed&rev_2210#000000123ad9&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}**

```
PartitionNr  Drive Offset               Size Type
-----------  ----- ------               ---- ----
0                  1016320         599.96 GB XINT13 Extended
4            A     1048576         599.96 GB IFS
1            F     644203929600    480.43 GB IFS
2            L     1845782118400       80 GB IFS
3            M     1931677270016       64 GB IFS
```

[image: DeepDive01]
[image: DeepDive02]
[image: DeepDive03]
[image: DeepDive04]
[image: DeepDive05]
[image: DeepDive06]
[image: DeepDive07]
[image: DeepDive08]
[image: DeepDive09]
[image: DeepDive10]
[image: DeepDive11]
[image: DeepDive12]
[image: DeepDive13]
[image: DeepDive14]

Comment: “Which of the 14 highlighted lines points to the unallocated partition?” - None of them. The other partitions have a file system. “If I re-allocated the 638GB unallocated part, would I then be able to undelete missing files on that partition?” - Based on your screenshots your data cannot be recovered. However, data recovery services do have other applications they have access to which might work, but TestDisk is clearly saying thr partition that was deleted cannot be recovered

Comment: There are three primary partitions and one extended partition in a very unusual configuration (extended first). No other partition can be created, unless you make the setup more standard xor even weirder; so *maybe* there has never been the fifth filesystem. If there was, it *probably* started at the end sector of the preceding partition plus one or few, ended at the start sector of the next partition minus one or few. The tools you used don't show what these sectors are. There is no way to simply create a partition there without touching other entries in the partition table.

Comment: Thank you, Ram&Kam! This is insightful, unlike the helpfiles of TestDisk. I guess that's just me.

Comment: So, @kamil-maciorowski, when you say: "No other partition can be created" are you referring to the 4 partition maximum there *used to be* under the MBR-scheme of partitioning?  Aren't more partitions possible under UEFI-schemes? This disk is formatted under UEFI.

 If there are only 4 partitions allowed, is re-allocating the unallocated part possible only **if** I combine two of the other partitions, so the total is 4 again? Or is my only option here, to add it to one of the neighbouring, adjacent, partitions? Thanks.

Comment: The presence of the "extended partition" and the "logical drive" strongly suggests it's a dos partition table in MBR. These terms simply do not belong to the GPT scheme. I can think of more than one option, but what exactly do you want now? Do you still want to recover files or the filesystem that allegedly used to be there? Or create a new filesystem? Or do you want to expand an existing filesystem? In any case it will be useful to know the output of (Linux) `fdisk -l` or any other tool that prints the *exact* start/end sectors for the partitions, expressed as LBA (not CHS).

Comment: what **windows 10** tool  can I use to determine/print the  exact start/end sectors for the partitions, expressed as LBA (not CHS)?
What I **want**, my **goal or object** is to find out if there are still lost files on the unallocated part and save them. I used DiskDrill, but it didn't say anything about that section, just about the 4 allocated partitions. The 2 smaller ones are copies of C-drives from other laptops.

Comment: using  Powershell command Get-Partition: 

 please see the **EDIT 1: ** above. Thanks

Comment: I find DMDE to be much easier to use i for this type of stuff, you can use the free version. https://youtu.be/F2PgrcxXrg8