# 95% of a partition on my external HDD is invisible and disk analyzing programs can't find it

Tags: windows, hard-drive, size

On my 2TB external HDD is a NTFS primary partition 480GB large.

[image: DiskMgmt.src]
Combined size of the files present is 18.5 GB, mostly the pagefile.sys and the free space is 256MB. 18.5GB  + 250MB is about 18.75GB, this does not equal 480GB so, about 460GB is missing

I've looked at this with **TreeFileSize**, and **WinDirStats** and even **Windows 10 storage app**, and this last one was the only one which had some sort of answer. See the pics.
Question: outside of re-format, how do I get this disk space back? Besides. I also would like the 437GB of videos back.
The partition and disk are accessible, for example I can move and resize partitions on it.

[image: WinDirStat]

[image: TreeSizeFree]

The only with some type of answer:
[image: Win10Storage]

filelist of partition

```
     Volume in drive F is F_2Terra
 Volume Serial Number is 65ED-2C20

 Directory of f:\

14-01-24  21:53    <DIR>          !F-film
11-06-22  02:43    <DIR>          F-toobig

27-04-22  06:07    <DIR>          FOUND.000
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of f:\!F-film

14-01-24  21:53    <DIR>          .
14-01-24  21:53    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of f:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-103424634-494602753-2214117543-1001

15-02-22  02:06               166 $I0ZRIK4.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               182 $I114GIO.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               230 $I5FUJ5F.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               164 $I6EHL04.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               164 $I6VPQ74.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               182 $I7Z8FEH.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               170 $I976F3W.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               226 $I9LMM0F.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               166 $IBI39E3.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               230 $IC6BSCI.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               180 $ICHYQ57.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               166 $ICT453H.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               166 $IFN4F05.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               164 $IGXTJVG.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               174 $IIGEZFK.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               170 $IJ4Q1SE.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               172 $IL7DUSX.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               168 $IL94RSY.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               280 $ILFUD1N.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               172 $ILHJWLN.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               240 $IMQEHJO.mkv
30-12-21  08:36               120 $IOPMO32
15-02-22  02:07               162 $IPEG5ZP.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               164 $IPGU0D1.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               178 $IR8K5GC.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               170 $ISLHAU0.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               172 $ISNHA8O.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               158 $IUE4HJ5.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               298 $IUQ6LF1.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               158 $IV214YL.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               270 $IVBMNMN.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               176 $IVFQ0CA.mkv
15-02-22  02:06               182 $IYDO8GZ.mkv
15-02-22  02:07               182 $IYM5BSZ.mkv
              34 File(s)          6.322 bytes

 Directory of f:\F-toobig

11-06-22  02:43    <DIR>          .
11-06-22  02:43    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of f:\FOUND.000

27-04-22  06:07    <DIR>          .
27-04-22  06:07    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of f:\found.000

27-04-22  06:07    <DIR>          .
27-04-22  06:07    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
              35 File(s)          6.322 bytes
              11 Dir(s)     266.874.880 bytes free
```

Comment: [I thought your disk already failed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1824121/i-need-help-make-sense-of-testdisk-output). Everything you present suggests a hardware problem

Comment: how can it be a hardware problem if the rest of the disk works fine? Also, based on the problem you referenced, how did you conclude the whole disk failed? Or that it was a hardware problem? Curious.

Comment: Check your recycle bin. I think all the videos etc are in there, and that is what takes up the space. Should also be in a hidden system folder F:\$RECYCLE.BIN

Comment: The size of the files in the recycle bin don’t appear to be correct

Comment: True, likely a disk failed thingy, but this will confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check

- Do you have system restore enabled for this drive? If so, how much space is allocated to that?
- Folders that you do not have permission on will not be analysed by tools looking at file sizes. Even if you run the program as admin there will be some folders that default to being unable to be read. It's likely some of the folders on that drive have files in them, but because you do not have read permission, it lists them as 0 bytes. Double check each of the folders to see that you can see all of their contents in file explorer. If not, give yourself permission on the folder, you may need to take ownership of the folder first to do so. Start with the folders marked as "found"
- The presense of the found folders indicates that the check disk passes found problems with the drive. Those folders typically have files or parts of files that the system lost, and chkdisk found. Given that mkv files are typically video files, they are normally a lot larger than those in the recycle bin, it may be the case the missing parts of those files are now in the found folders.
- Since there were filesystem errors you may also have parts of the drive marked as bad sectors consuming space with no files occupying that space. This is not likely the culprit, as you'd long ago tossed the drive out before it reached 20% missing space.
- Do any of the files have alternate data streams? You can use the tool from https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html to find them if you don't know another way.

Launch a command prompt window as admin and run the chkdisk command again and see how much of the partition is allocated to each type

```
  C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk f:
  The type of the file system is NTFS.
  Volume label is OS.

  Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  ... blah blah blah ...

  Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  ... blah blah blah ...

  Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
  ... blah blah blah ...

  Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
  No further action is required.

   965193308 KB total disk space.
   193386256 KB in 702532 files.
      513388 KB in 297888 indexes.  <--- if this is huge defrag the partition.
           0 KB in bad sectors.    <------ you may have some of this, if you do the physical disk is on its last leg, backup your data now and replace the disk.
     1496768 KB in use by the system.  <---- or lots of this
       65536 KB occupied by the log file.  <--- or this
   769796896 KB available on disk.

        4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
   241298327 total allocation units on disk.
   192449224 allocation units available on disk.
  Total duration: 4.83 minutes (289944 ms).
```

Comment: nope, no system restore and I ran both programs as admin. I  didnt know that about found folders and chkdsk, thanks. ill let you know the rest.

Comment: @GwenKillerby just running a program as admin will not give you instant access to all folders and files. There are usually some folders that ONLY have permission to SYSTEM and not even the admin can read the content, even if you have enabled viewing hidden and system files/folders. For those folders you need to give yourself permission on the folder, and for some you need to take ownership first. Both tasks can be done from the folder properties -> securty tab -> advanced button